# C# XMLRPC Custom Fields

Tags: c#, xml-rpc

Im trying to to write a program in C# and I'm stuck. The program suppose to create a post on wordpress via xmlrpc. I can create the post successfully but I have problems creating custom fields for the post. So when I open created post, custom fields are never there. I hope some of you gurus can help me as I am stuck for 3 days now and cant figure out what to do, feel absolutely helpless:(

Heres some code:

```
public struct customField
        {
            public string key;
            public string value; 
        }
        public struct newPost
        {
            public string[] categories;
            public string title;
            public string description;
            public string mt_excerpt;
            public customField[] cf;
        }
public interface IcreatePost
       {
           [CookComputing.XmlRpc.XmlRpcMethod("metaWeblog.newPost")]
           string NewPost(int blogId, string strUserName,
               string strPassword, newPost content, int publish);
       }
```

Heres how I set values for the object

```
    customField newCustomField2 = default(customField);

    newCustomField2.key = "some data";

    newCustomField2.value = "some data";


    newPost newBlogPost = default(newPost);
    newBlogPost.title = "Some Title";
    newBlogPost.description = "Some Content";
    newBlogPost.cf = new customField[] { newCustomField2 };
createPost(newBlogPost);
```

Function called:

```
public void createPost(newPost np)
        {

            string postid;
            icp = (IcreatePost)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IcreatePost));
            clientProtocol = (XmlRpcClientProtocol)icp;
            clientProtocol.Url = "http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc.php";
            try
            {
                postid = icp.NewPost(1, "admin", "1234", np, 1); 

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("createPost ERROR ->"+ ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My only guess here would be that there is a naming mismatch in your parameters. The documentation that I've seen says that the field inside the newPost struct should be `custom_fields` rather than `cf`:

```
public struct newPost
{
    public string[] categories;
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public string mt_excerpt;
    public customField[] custom_fields;
}
```